# C# Second text box filling out with random names

Tags: c#

this is my code and I also have a snippet in the link below of what my program looks like when run. My problem is with the second text box and that it is filling out with random gibberish. My first text box is working perfectly it is picking a random first name from my text file and putting it into the text box. I dont understand what my second text file isnt doing the same'?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        { 
            Random r = new Random();
            int currentLinefirst = 1;
            string pick = null;

            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\C# Programs\\WindowsFormsApplication5\\WindowsFormsApplication5\\First Names.txt"))
            {
                if (r.Next(currentLinefirst) == 0)
                {
                    pick = line;
                }
                ++currentLinefirst;                    
            }
            textBox1.Text = pick;                
        }

        Random n = new Random();
        int currentLinelast = 1;
        string pick2 = null;
        foreach (string line1 in File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\C# Programs\\WindowsFormsApplication5\\WindowsFormsApplication5\\Last Names.txt"))
        {
            if (n.Next(currentLinelast) == 0)
            {
                pick2 = line1;
            }

            ++currentLinelast;
        }
        textBox2.Text = pick2;            
    }
 }
 }
```

i am getting this output of random numbers in textbox

[image]

Comment: if you don't mind, can you show us your textfile.

Comment: please attach the txt file

Comment: This is my first names and last names text documents https://github.com/wulfcare/Noob-Code

Comment: did you solve the problem with last name?

Comment: I try to reproduce the error. However, when I copy and paste your code into a new project, everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because your second file contains a line with multiple names. When you call File.ReadLines, it will return an array of string on each line

Try separating you last names with line feeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string firstname = textBox1.Text;
string lastname = textBox2.Text;
Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(firstname + lastname);

string FilePath = yourpath + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ".txt";

using (FileStream fs = File.Create(FilePath))
      {fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the text to a text file use

```
 using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine("First Name: {0}  Last Name: {1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
            }
```

`{0}` and `{1}` are placeholders

if the file is does not  exist it will create a new file to the given path and if the file already exists then it will add new entry to the file.